# Get data from another table based on id in different table

Tags: entity-framework

I have following tables

Cart : CartId, ProductId,UserId,PromoCodeId

Promocode : Id, Name , Discount
(Promocodeid is not a foreign key)

I want to get name of promocode from PromoCodeId in MVC using EF, i can not set foreign key because I also want to allow null values in PromoCodeId of cart table. how to achieve it?

Comment: A "forign key" does allow  nulls in the referring table.

Comment: that is why I have not set PromoCode id as foreign key in Cart table, but now how to get PromoCode name based on the PromoCode Id in the cart table.

Comment: I'm just saying you can very well set it as a foreign key.

Comment: And `PromoCodeId` should be a nullable field in the db and a nullable type in the the C# code. If you need more help we have to see your code.

Comment: thanks for your time..working now :-)